# error java.lang.LinkageError when using cxf in karaf

Tags: osgi, cxf, apache-karaf, camel-cxf, apache-karaf-feature

i am using cxf 3.3.5 and karaf 4.2.7
I have an application that is a soap client and makes requests for a soap service, if no errors occur on the remote service, then everything is fine, but when an exception occurs, then I see an error for the place of correct error handling

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault"
    at javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException.<init>(SOAPFaultException.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.insupdDevice(Unknown Source)
```

as far as i understood the problem is in package javax.xml.soap package  which was loaded saaj-api(was installed during feature:install cxf)

I saw the topic http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Loader-constraint-violation-javax-xml-soap-SOAPFault-td4056103.html, but as far as I understood there is still no solution

any ideas?

Comment: my solution: edit jre.propirties, add javax.xml.soap for 1.8(it is very strange why it is not for version 1.8, but there is for earlier versions), uninstall bundle saaj-api and restart karaf

Comment: I added javax.xml.soap, saaj-api is not listed in my case, but this didn't resolve in my case

Comment: ok, found and removed saaj-api and now the LinkageError is gone